# how to remove the first <p>.......[content]</p>[start and end tag only ] with html parser or regex

Tags: regex, html-parsing

```
String  s  = "<p>test with only p tag </p>";
```

output should be `test with only p tag`

```
String  t  = "<p>test with only p tag </p><p></p>";
```

output should be `test with only p tag <p></p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<=<p>).+(?=</p>)
```

should work

Comment: This is removing the content . i want the removal of tags <p></p>